# Springer template - Citations breaking text width

Tags: bibtex, citing, journal

I am using a Springer template for journals, in the Overleaf editor. The document class is below:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
```

For the references, I am using the following style:

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
```

When I cite some work, the reference is appearing too long, breaking the text width. Instead of just show `[Author1 et al.(2020)]`, it is showing `[Author1 et al.(2020)Author1, Author2, ..., AuthorN]`.

Any hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the preamble of the file `spbasic.bst`:

```
 % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
 % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
 % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly
```

The upshot? Make sure your document loads the `natbib` citation management package.